# MVC3 Re-installation VS2010 SP1

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3

I've looked [here](http://VS10-KB2483190-x86.exe%29%20failed%20with%200x80070643%20-%20Fatal%20error%20during%20installation.%20.) and the [link in the solution](http://blog.mjjames.co.uk/2010/12/mvc-3-rc2-install-error-0x80070643.html) but I'm still having problems.  I had Visual Studio 2010 with SP1 beta and MVC3 installed but encountered no Intellisense on cshtml files and problems with System.Web.Helpers not being found.

Downloaded the released VS2010 SP1 and installed this (as recommended, over the beta) and still had the issue so uninstalled MVC3.

Now I can't install MVC3 at all, the log shows VS10-KB2483190-x86.exe) failed with 0x80070643 - Fatal error during installation and even when opening the MVC3 exe in 7-zip and installing components individually as per the blog.

Has anyone else had a similar problem that they manage to solve?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This blog](http://blog.mjjames.co.uk/2010/12/mvc-3-rc2-install-error-0x80070643.html) did work, as described in the question.  Downloaded the standalone installer of MVC3 and got the individual files using 7-zip.

Beforehand, I uninstalled ASP.NET Web Pages with a guide in [this post](http://forums.asp.net/p/1661809/4338305.aspx/1?Re+Problem+installing+MVC+3) which talks about removing trailing slashes from the registry first.

Now MVC3 works and also the System.Web.Helpers and IDependencyResolver is found which was another reason for re-installing.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping this surface, we ran into this issue in a slightly different environment but this worked.

Answer (score 4):

Get your visual studio dvd, or download the iso trial and mount it.  Then run the mvc3 setup.  I ran the vs10-kb2483190-x86 by itself and it complained about not finding the vs setup.msi from the dvd.

Answer (score 2):

I was unable to install MVC with the same error and Paul's solution worked for me. Many thanks. I did not have to perform the Registry mods in my particular case though. So,

1. Uninstall Microsoft ASP .NET Web Pages from Add/Remove Programs
2. Run the setup for MVC 3. This will unpack the setup files to C:\Temp\ext47334
3. Run C:\Temp\ext47334\aspnetwebpages.msi
4. Run the rest of the msis in C:\Temp\ext47334

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem of a failed installation using the web installer (though it reported success).  But in my case, I had already installed MVC4 before I tried installing MVC3.

I downloaded the offline installer, which failed with the same error as above.  I then tried both suggestions of inserting the VS2010 DVD, and changing the registry paths as described, but neither worked.  I then tried first uninstalling the MVC3 stuff from Program and Features in Control Panel.  This time the installation got further than before, but failed on installing NuGet.  So I *uninstalled NuGet* and reran the installer, this time with success!  I then had to reinstall NuGet by downloading the latest version from the http://nuget.org/.